# Why can't the laity preach a homily, and can a lay person ever preach?

Tags: catholicism, mass, canon-law

From this, [Rochester diocese ends illicit practice of allowing lay people to preach homilies](http://www.catholicculture.org/news/headlines/index.cfm?storyid=22073), perhaps because this was going on for such a long time, a person would ask what is the authoritative Catholic Church Teaching that prohibits a lay person (of either gender) from preaching the homily at Mass and are there cases where the laity may (men or women) can be allowed to preach in a church or oratory? Under what circumstances?

Comment: Answer is [here](http://canonlawmadeeasy.com/2014/05/08/when-are-the-laity-permitted-to-preach/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code of Canon Law states:

> 766.0 **Lay persons can be permitted to preach in a church or oratory**, if necessity requires it in certain circumstances or it seems advantageous in particular cases, according to the prescripts of the conference of bishops and without prejudice to 767.1
>
> 767.1. Among the forms of preaching, **the homily, which is part of the liturgy** itself and is **reserved to a priest or deacon**, is preeminent; (....)

So, non-ordained faithful can preach, but NOT in the Mass. Because homily in the mass is a part of the liturgy which is reserved to the cleric (priest and deacon) alone. The reason for this is answered in [Instruction On Certain Questions Regarding The Collaboration Of The Non-Ordained Faithful In The Sacred Ministry Of Priest](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/pontifical_councils/laity/documents/rc_con_interdic_doc_15081997_en.html) Article 3.1

> The homily, therefore, during the celebration of the Holy Eucharist, must be reserved to the sacred minister, Priest or Deacon(69) to the exclusion of the non-ordained faithful....  This exclusion of the lay people is not based on their preaching ability of sacred ministers nor their theological preparation, but on that **function which is reserved to them** in virtue of having received the Sacrament of Holy Orders. For the same reason the diocesan Bishop cannot validly dispense from the canonical norm since this is not merely a disciplinary law but one which touches upon the **closely connected functions of teaching and sanctifying**.

---

*PS: 'The homily should ordinarily be given by the priest celebrant himself. He may entrust it to a concelebrating priest or occasionally, according to circumstances, to the deacon, but never to a lay person. In particular cases and for a just cause, the homily may even be given by a bishop or a priest who is present at the celebration but cannot concelebrate.' [(GIRM 66)](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/ccdds/documents/rc_con_ccdds_doc_20030317_ordinamento-messale_en.html#B._The_Liturgy_of_the_Word_)*

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a fine line though in what is an homily and another form of reflection. For instance, [this article](https://www.uscatholic.org/laypreachers) states:

> As was the case with my own “reflection” at Sunday Mass (technically, a layperson cannot give a “homily”), many pastors do currently allow people other than priests and deacons to speak at Mass. It may be directly about the readings for that Mass, or it could be on a different topic that is relevant to the parish community. Occasionally it is just a talk by a member of the parish finance committee. [...]
>
> In such cases the celebrating priest often gives a short homily or just makes a few comments before turning it over to the layperson. Pastors have mentioned to me that they often have to fend off criticism from a few folks for allowing laypeople to speak at Mass, but they make these exceptions in cases where there is an important message best delivered by someone with an expertise. [...]
>
> It is suggested that laypersons may speak at other types of events, outside of Mass. In certain circumstances, they can speak during Mass, but this should never be confused with a homily.

Another gray area is that regarding the **reading** of the homily. Although the sermon can certainly be produced by the priest, it seems it could well be read by a layperson. This might well open the door to homilies which are prepared my priests in communion with laypersons.